# how does one decompose the defining permutation representation of the symmetric group into irreducible representations?

Tags: symmetric-groups

For all n > 2, how does one decompose the defining permutation representation of the symmetric group $S_n$ into
irreducible representations?

Comment: Depends. Does one start with knowledge of all the irreducible representations? Then, it's easy. If not, then, it's hard, and gets harder the larger $n$ is.

Comment: @Gerry I would understand "defining permutation representation" as the degree $n$ one, in which case the answer is essentially the same in all cases (in char 0).